# AWS wildcard subdomains - parent domain on different service provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, wildcard-subdomain

I need to map all subdomains to single S3 bucket, but my parent domain is registered and used on different service provider (GoDaddy).
E.g.:

- domain example.com registered in GoDaddy
- https://example.com used for website hosted on GoDaddy
- all subdomain https://[subdomain_name].example.com - redirected to single S3 bucket

How to configure AWS to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that directly on S3 , S3 matches bucket based on the HOST header browser is passing and it should match exactly with the bucket name.

You can use CloudFront and define S3 as an origin.
In CloudFront, you can use cert for *.example.com and also add this into the CNAME/Alternative Name filed of CloudFront.

Godaddy supports wildcard record, you can CNAME it to CloudFront dns name.

https://in.godaddy.com/help/set-up-wildcard-dns-3301

Comment: I try to generete certificate for *.example.com in Certificate Manager and I still have status Pending validation. Should I do something more? Do I have to use Route 53 to redirect all subdomains from GoDaddy to single S3 bucket?

Comment: For certificate you can use either dns or email validation